# Symfony2 FOSRestBundle handleView() doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

Just created a new project with symfony2 and installed FOSRestBundle. 
Controller example:

```
<?php

namespace ApiBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;


class TestController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function TestAction()
    {
        $data = array ('1', '2', '3', 'four'); // get data, in this case list of users.
        $view = $this->view($data, 200)
            ->setTemplate("ApiBundle:Test:test.html.twig")
            ->setTemplateVar('test')
        ;

        return $this->handleView($view);       
    }

}
```

Got error message:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "fos_rest.view_handler".
```

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `AppKernel`, be sure you have the following:

```
// app/config/AppKernel.php
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
    );
}
```

You surely forgotten [this step](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/1-setting_up_the_bundle.html).